# How do I send an HTTP request in this format?

Tags: http, http-1.1

```
POST /api/crmteetimeapi.asmx/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: golffacility.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

OwnerID=string&UserID=string&Password=string
```

What language do I use?

Forgive my ignorance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any server side language...

In php:

```
$host = "golffacility.com";
$fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $content = 'OwnerID=string&UserID=string&Password=string';
    $contentLength = mb_strlen($content);
    $out = "POST /api/crmteetimeapi.asmx/Login / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: $host\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-Length: $contentLength\r\n\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

In html:

```
<form action="http://golffacility.com/api/crmteetimeapi.asmx/Login" method="post">
<input name="OwnerID" value="string"/>
<input name="UserID" value="string"/>
<input name="Password" value="string"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then click "submit" ;)